# How to create simple JavaScript "class"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple JS class and then trying to create an object but in the marked row it says "Cannot read property 'show' of undefined".

```
function DashboardNumberItem(dashboardItemId, dataUrl) {
    this.dashBoardItem = $("#" + dashboardItemId);
    this.dataurl = dataUrl;
    this.placeholder = $("#" + dashboardItemId + " .number-placeholder");
    this.dashBoardItem.hide();
}

DashboardNumberItem.prototype.loadData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.dataurl,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            this.dashBoardItem.show(); // this.dashBoardItem is undefined?!
            this.placeholder.text(data);
        }
    });
};

var dashboardItem = new DashboardNumberItem("dashboard-item-vardhandelseimportcount", "/Controller/Action");
dashboardItem.loadData();
```

Why does this happen and how can I make it work?

Comment: Not sure how _jQuery_ does it, but `this` in an _XMLHttpRequest's_ callback usually points to the request, not the Object which created the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` probably isn't what you expect it to be, and will be pointing to *jQuery's XMLHttpRequest Object* rather than your `DashboardNumberItem` instance, so set up a new variable e.g. `var that = this;`

```
DashboardNumberItem.prototype.loadData = function() {
    var that = this; // set up a reference to capture it
    $.ajax({
        url: that.dataurl,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            that.dashBoardItem.show(); // which you can now use in another context
            that.placeholder.text(data);
        }
    });
};
```